# I have an arbitrary amount of files I need written to a multi-sheet excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, excel, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to pull attachments from Outlook and save certain parts of that data to an excel sheet. I have the data already pulled, but I need the data from each MONTH it was sent on its own sheet. I was going to create multiple dataframes, but I'd have to create 12 data frames to do this. Is there a shorter way to do it?

Here's the code I'm using to pull the data out of the txt files.

```
def save_attachments(folder_name):
    output_dir = Path.cwd() / "RRD Reconciliation Attachments"
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders[folder_name]
    donebox =  mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["done_box"]
    output = pd.DataFrame()

    for message in inbox.Items:
            attachments = message.Attachments
            for attachment in attachments:
                sent_date = message.SentOn.strftime("%m_%d_%y")
                new_name = str(attachment).split(".")[2] + "_" + sent_date + ".txt"
                attachment.SaveAsFile(output_dir / new_name)
                sheets_names = message.SentOn.strftime("%B")
                # message.Move(donebox)
    for f_name in os.listdir(output_dir):
        print(f_name)
        os.chdir(output_dir)
        with open(f_name) as data:
            details = False
            skip = False
            columns = []
            d = {}
            for line in map(str.rstrip, data):
                if skip:
                    skip = False
                    continue
                tokens = line.split()
                if len(tokens) == 0:
                    continue
                if details:
                    if len(tokens) != len(columns):
                        break
                    for token, column in zip(tokens, columns):
                        d.setdefault(column, []).append(token)
                else:
                    if tokens[0] == 'Description':
                        details = True
                        skip = True
                        columns = tokens
                    else:
                        if len(tokens) == 2 and tokens[0][-1] == ':':
                            d[tokens[0][:-1]] = tokens[1]
        os.chdir(r'C:\Users\C974776\OneDrive - Constellation\Desktop\python tools')
        output['Filename'] = f_name
        output = output.append(d, ignore_index=True)
        output = output[['Filename', 'Batch', 'Copy', 'Order', 'Run', 'Description']]
        output = output.drop(columns=['DOCUMENTS', 'PAGES', 'SHEETS', 'PAGES*', 'SHEETS*'], errors='ignore')
        output.to_excel('rrd_recon.xlsx', sheet_name=sheets_names)
```